# How to find maximum time from array?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I have an array. I want to find the maximum time from array.

I tried the follwing code.

`var maxtm =  Math.max.apply(null, this.my_arr.map(function (e) {
       return e['time'];
}));`

`this.my_arr = [{
  date: '21-jun-2019',
  time: '21:22:00'
}, {
  date: '21-june-2019',
  time: '11:33:23',
}, {
  date: '21-june-2019',
  time: '12:12:00'
}]`

I expect the output '21:22:00', but the actual output is NaN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try convert to int parseInt(time.split(':').join(''), 10)

Example

var maxtm = Math.max.apply(null, this.my_arr.map(function (e) { return parseInt(e['time'].split(':').join(''), 10);}));

After you need convert max back to time

Comment: how to use int parseInt(time.split(':').join(''), 10)

Comment: Thanks... its work for me. If i want to return row then how can i get.